# Copy Point From Tikz to Tkz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I simply want to know the way from TikZ to Tkz, because the reverse method is pretty straightforward.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
    \node at (A){A};
    \draw[name path=line1] (A) -- (4,2);
    \draw[name path=line2] (2,0) -- (2,4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by={B}}] (B) circle (2pt);
%   \tkzDefPoint(B){CopyOfB} % that's not right, isn't it?
%   \node at (CopyOfB){B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Um, `B` is defined using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) commands so you can use `\node at (B){node at B};`. More generally, [tkz-euclide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) is built on top of [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) so provided you know what to "call" you will be able access [tkz-euclide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide)  through [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz).

Comment: You may be right for this MWE, but that is only a demonstration. In the end my goal is to use a point with tkz mechanics, e.g. above a pgf-plot. BUT tkz only allows a definition with X,Y arguments (not to mention the def by an arc), because its based on the '\coordinate' macro. So my question remains how to copy the information (where the coordinates are calculated and not user defined aka known from the beginning) from one to the other.

Comment: I don't understand your question or your answer to @Andrew. Can you explain more explicitly the problem you're facing, what you would like to do and what's failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with intern macros from `tkz-euclide` (page 128 of the new documentation 3.05 Miscellaneous tools)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
    \node at (A){A};
    \draw[name path=line1] (A) -- (4,2);
    \draw[name path=line2] (2,0) -- (2,4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by={B}}] (B) circle (2pt);
    \tkzGetPointCoord(B){V}
    \tkzDefPoint(\Vx,\Vy){copyB}
     \tkzDrawPoint[red](copyB)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! +1. (But you may want to also invert the transformation, if you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm]...` the red point is off.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat      You are right :) but `[x=2cm]` is not allowed (recommended) with `tkz-euclide` I do not guarantee that all macros will work properly.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i was looking for (and didn't find it with v3.02).

BTW: i chose this as answer because of the build-in functionality

Comment: @Venez Now version 3.05 is on CTAN

Answer (score 3):

You can always extract the coordinates of a point and use them. This can be used to define a macro that "copies" Ti*k*Z points to tkz. (Note that this version of the macro assumes you did not customize the coordinates, i.e. you didn't redefine `x` nor `y`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\newcommand{\CopyPointToTkz}[2]{\path (#1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\macroxcm}{\macrox/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\macroycm}{\macroy/1cm}
    \tkzDefPoint(\macroxcm,\macroycm){#2}
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
    \node at (A){A};
    \draw[name path=line1] (A) -- (4,2);
    \draw[name path=line2] (2,0) -- (2,4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by={B}}] (B) circle (2pt);
    \CopyPointToTkz{B}{CopyOfB}
    \node at (CopyOfB){B};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to allow for arbitrary redefinitions of the coordinate system, you need to go a bit more complicated.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\CopyPointToTkz}[2]{\path (#1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\macroxcm}{\macrox/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\macroycm}{\macroy/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mya}{\pgf@xx/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{\pgf@yx/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myc}{\pgf@xy/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myd}{\pgf@yy/1cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydet}{\mya*\myd-\myb*\myc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myxx}{\myd/\mydet}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myxy}{-\myc/\mydet}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myyx}{-\myb/\mydet}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myyy}{\mya/\mydet}
    \tkzDefPoint(\macroxcm*\myxx+\macroycm*\myyx,\macroxcm*\myxy+\macroycm*\myyy){#2}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm]
    \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
    \node at (A){A};
    \draw[name path=line1] (A) -- (4,2);
    \draw[name path=line2] (2,0) -- (2,4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by={B}}] (B) circle (2pt);
    \CopyPointToTkz{B}{CopyOfB}
    \node at (CopyOfB){B};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes and this is possible directly with `tkz-euclide`